# Radio button returns undefined

Tags: javascript, button

Radio button keeps returning undefined. I looked it up, tried answers from other similar questions, but I just get undefined when I add the value to a table.

This is my javascript code to get the value from the button.

```
var grade="";
        var grades = document.getElementsByName('grade');
        for(var i=0;i<grades.length;i++)
        {
            if(grades[i].checked)
                grade = grades[i].value;
        }
```

And here is my html code

```
<div><label>Grade</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="5" name="grade">5</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="6" name="grade">6</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="7" name="grade">7</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="8" name="grade">8</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="9" name="grade">9</label>
<label><input type="radio" value="10" name="grade">10</label></div>
```

I copied this code from a similar page with radio buttons and that one works as intended. All I did was change the name and values.

EDIT:
This is the code that adds a new row with all the inputted information

```
var tbody = document.getElementsByTagName("tbody")[0]
                tbody.innerHTML += "<tr><td>" + name.value + "</td>" + "<td>" + index.value + "</td>" + "<td>" + phone.value + "" +
                    "</td>" + "<td>" + grade.value + "</td>" + "<td>" + session.value + "</td>"
                name.value = ""
                index.value = ""
                phone.value = ""
                grade.value = ""
            }
```

Comment: What is triggering your javascript code?

Comment: A button triggers the function

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/zgtbh2cs/ Your code works fine. Please provide a snippet that reproduces your problem.

Comment: If you set `grade = grades[i].value` then `grade.value` is equivalent to `grades[i].value.value`. Just print `grade` in the table.

Comment: When you fill your table you use `grade.value` however you only store a tekst into the variable when doing `grade = grades[i].value;`.  Therefore the value property will not exist in the grade variable. Just use `grade` instead.

Comment: FYI, you don’t need to loop over the radio buttons, if you just access them via the forms collection … `document.forms[0].grade.value` always gets you the value of the currently checked radio button (assumung the form they are in is the first one on the page, with index `0`.) Or something like `document.querySelector('#formID').grade.value` or similar.

Answer (score 0):

So I fixed it by changing grade.value to grade in tbody.innerHTML